# Calculating sum in 2d array for each row

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

i'm very new to C++ and im trying to do some exercise about data handling and 2d array
so my problem is I seems to get weird results when im trying to run this code that i write to calculate the sum of 1st row in 2d array and the datafile that i use should look like this

```
1 19 93 92 87
1 20 76 87 75
1 19 75 87 80
1 22 86 23 30
1 20 89 82 29
1 21 28 39 31
1 22 39 21 49
1 20 40 39 19
1 20 22 11 22
1 19 75 90 15
```

this is the code that i use

```
void sumRow(){
    int data [10][5];
    float sum;
    ifstream f("datafile.txt");
    for(int row = 0; row < 10; row++){
        for(int column = 0; column < 5; column++){
            f >> data[row][column];
        }
    }
    for (int column = 2; column < 5;column++){
        sum+= data[1][column];
    }
    cout << sum;
}
```

Comment: What is the weird output you are seeing?

Comment: Why are you starting at the third column when adding the values of the row?

Comment: `float sum;` -- Did your compiler warn you about uninitialized variables?  Your program has undefined behavior, since you are adding `data[1][column]` to an uninitialized `float` variable called `sum`.

Comment: Finally, fixed it! i mistyped the number of column and it seems like i forgot to initialized sum to 0. Thank you so much. I would not notice it by my own

Comment: It is considered to be bad practice to hide a `}` at the end of a line.

Comment: Ok, i'll try to fix that bad habit of mine as well

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't your first row index be 0 instead of 1 and if you want sum of all the elements of first row then why start the for loop with column = 2 rather than column = 0.

Answer (score 1):

The index of the first row (and column) on arrays in c++ is 0, so if you want to calculate the sum of the items on the first row you should do:

```
for (int column = 0; column < 5; column++){
    sum += data[0][column];
}
```